# Circle degrees loop in Angular Leaflet

Tags: math, leaflet, trigonometry, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to create circle degrees in Angular leaflet maps
In my first step i have applied formulas for 30 45 degrees and so on
as

```
const x30: number = p.x + (radius) * (Math.cos(Math.PI / 6));
const y30: number = p.y + (radius) * (Math.sin(Math.PI / 6));

const x45: number = p.x + (radius) * (Math.cos(Math.PI / 4));
const y45: number = p.y + (radius) * (Math.sin(Math.PI / 4));
```

but now i want to have a for loop that starts according to my selected values of drop-down
like if i select 10  then my loop should start from 10 and should have distance of 10 degree
means now i have to find (x,y) for 10 20 30 degrees and so on
now my question is that what should be the series of degrees that i should use in for loop?
or what should be the option to get degree form Math Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your question is on converting degrees to radians. Recall that there are 2PI radians in a circle and 360 degrees. 2PIradians and 360degrees measure the same angle. So, 2PIradians = 360degrees. To convert from degrees to radians, you need to divide by 360 and then multiply by 2PI; equivalently, multiply by PI/180. Using this formula, we can calculate the corresponding angle measure in radians for any angle measure given in degrees. Here's a table:

```
degrees    radians
 0         (PI/180)*0  = 0
 5         (PI/180)*5  = PI/36
10         (PI/180)*10 = PI/18
15         (PI/180)*15 = PI/12
20         (PI/180)*20 = PI/9
25         (PI/180)*25 = 5PI/36
30         (PI/180)*30 = PI/6
35         (PI/180)*35 = 7PI/36
40         (PI/180)*40 = 4PI/18
45         (PI/180)*45 = PI/4
50         (PI/180)*50 = 5*PI/18
55         (PI/180)*55 = 11*PI/36
60         (PI/180)*60 = PI/3
65         (PI/180)*65 = 13*PI/36
70         (PI/180)*70 = 7*PI/18
75         (PI/180)*75 = 15*PI/36
80         (PI/180)*80 = 4*PI/9
85         (PI/180)*85 = 17*PI/36
90         (PI/180)*90 = PI/2
```

Comment: yes i am looking for degrees in radians, but was confused with all values and may be a little knowledge of math forced me to asked this question . well your answer is what i was looking for. Thank you.